# Java JSF h:inputTextarea and output Textarea on same page?

Tags: html, jsf

My code looks like this:

```
<h:form>
<h:inputTextarea value="#{spintax.content}" cols="30" rows="10" />
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="spinned" />
</h:form>
```

It takes some content, changes it and gives a response on spinned.xhtml page as outputText. I'd like to do the same, but I need this to stay on the same page and output as Textarea (not outputText). Output textarea should be under inputTextarea. Is it possible ? So you put some content on text area and get response on same text area under it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. There are several ways to achieve it. I'll show two:

- Having the `<h:inputTextarea>` outside the `<h:form>`:

  ```
  <h:form>
      <h:inputTextarea value="#{spintax.content}" cols="30" rows="10" />
      <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="spinned" />
  </h:form>
  <h:inputTextarea value="#{spintax.output}" cols="30" rows="10" />
  ```
- Using a managed bean to process the data and ajax:

  Facelets code:

  ```
  <h:form>
      <h:inputTextarea id="itaContent" value="#{spintax.content}" cols="30" rows="10" />
      <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{spintax.process}">
          <f:ajax render="itaOutput" execute="itaContent" />
      </h:commandButton>
      <h:inputTextArea id="itaOutput" value="#{spintax.content}" />
  </h:form>
  ```

  Managed bean code:

  ```
  @ViewScoped
  @ManagedBean
  public class Spintax {
      private String content;
      //proper getter/setter
      public void process() {
          //process the content if needed...
          //otherwise, do nothing
      }
  }
  ```